# How can I add multiple bootstrap hosts in the MarkLogic cluster using MarkLogic API?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have to create multiple bootstrap hosts in the clusters using marklogic API during deployment using ml-gradle.

I know I can configure it by admin console (8001 port) but I am not able to figure out how can I add multiple bootstrap hosts in the MarkLogic cluster using MarkLogic API?

[image: Edit Local Cluster Configuration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following case worked in **Postman**:

```
HTTP Verb:
PUT

Authorization:
Digest Auth admin:admin

Header: 
Content-Type application/json

URI:
{ml-host}:8002/manage/v2/hosts/{new-bootstrap-host}/properties

Body:
{
    "bootstrap-host": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you are referring to the [Management API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management).  If that's the case, then you can POST against the hosts endpoint to define bootstrap hosts

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/hosts

```
cat myHost.json
==> 

{
  "host-name": "hostname1",
  "group": "",
  "bind-port": 8090,
  "foreign-bind-port": 9091,
  "zone": "",
  "bootstrap-host": true
}

curl -X POST --digest -u admin:admin -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d @myHost.json http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/hosts 

==>  Defines the host, named "hostname1," as the bootstrap host in 
     the cluster.
```

Comment: Getting error status: 405 Method not allowed

"REST-UNSUPPORTEDMETHOD: (err:FOER0000) Endpoint does not support method: POST"

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap host -> dh5a**

**Target joining host -> dh5b**

1. Save dh5b config as dh5b-config.xml

```
curl -o dh5b-config.xml --user {authen-user:passwd} \
-X GET -H "Content-type:application/xml" \
http://dh5b:8001/admin/v1/server-config
```

2. Send dh5b config to dh5a as cluster-config.zip

```
curl --digest --user {authen-user:passwd} -X POST -o cluster-config.zip -d "group=Default" \
--data-urlencode "server-config@./dh5b-config.xml" \
-H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
http://dh5a:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config
```

3. Send cluster-config.zip to dh5b and complete the joining process

```
curl --anyauth --user {authen-user:passwd} -X POST -H "Content-type: application/zip" \
--data-binary @./cluster-config.zip \
http://dh5b:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config
```

For production deployment:

> 1) Use Gradle to deploy additional hosts if Gradle is permitted
>
> 2) Write/Execute Shell script to include above API operations
>
> > (This approach has a lot more fun: combination of old Shell and modern API)
>
> You can then use automation tool to invoke Shell or Gradle.